# Convert AJAX Response of Objects Array to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a sample endpoint here which has a JSON data, but for any reason I do not understand why it does return `[object Object]`.

[Mock API](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

I have a previous code which was a bit confusing, but luckily I saw another answer that was clearer.

```
function generateTable(data, selId){

    var cnt = "<table border=1>";

    cnt += "<tr>";
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key,value){
       cnt += "<td><strong>" + key + "</strong></td>";
    });
   cnt += "<tr>";

   /* cnt += "<tr>";
   $.each(obj, function(key,value){
       cnt += "<td>" + value + "</td>";
   });
   cnt += "<tr>"; */ This part was commented because the conversion above does not work.
   cnt += "</table>";

   $(selId).html(cnt);

}

function createTableData(APIurl, selId){
    $.getJSON("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", function(data){
          generateTable(data, selId);
    });
}
```

When I try to alert the data returned, it return `[object Object], [object Object], ...` and so on. How do I convert the JSON data from the API to an array where I can access inside my `generateTable` function? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the `console.log()` instead of `alert`. And it looks like you've got an object back already, so you don't need to `JSON.parse()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the array

```
var cnt = "<table border=1>";
for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++){
    var row = data[i];
    cnt += "<tr>";
    $.each(row, function(key,value){
       cnt += "<td><strong>" + key + "</strong></td>";
    });
   cnt += "</tr>";
}
cnt += "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to debug that one. It works for the console. However, it does not reflect in the HTML.

Comment: You still need to use the `$(selId).html(cnt);` i just included the part that needed edits.

Comment: That one works like  a charm. Now, I am trying to loop once over the keys of the object. However it returns `0,1,2,3...` How do I loop over `"name, "age", etc."`? I tried using `Object.keys` but it didn't work. Thanks. @GabyakaGPetrioli